# PgAdmin can not show existing database after rename

Tags: pgadmin-4

The problem is that PgAdmin not show me database after rename. It is funny that I can execute queries to this database using query tool, but there is no renamed database in list of databases. How can I add my renamed database in list of databases?
Thank you.

I tried to refresh server, no results.
I tried to modify pg_hba.conf file to method "trust", no results.
I tried to reinstall my PgAgent, no results.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of pgAdmin. The postgres database is default name for pgAdmin. If you rename it, pgAdmin stop show renamed database postgres in his three. If you need specific name of your database you have to create new one and work with it.If you want to see your renamed database ex postgres you have to rename it back.